# How to skip JSON data on some condition

Tags: android, json

I am stuck on this for weeks. I'm tryin to skip some data from json if the value of `online` is 0.
This is my Json:

```json
[{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Carol",
    "online": "1"

}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Tom",
    "online": "0"


}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Joy",
    "online": "1"

}]
```

If the value of `online` is 0 then i would like to parse this on my listview:

```json
[{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Carol",
    "online": "1"

}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Joy",
    "online": "1"

}]
```

Which means that we skipped the block of json having `online` value as 0.
Is this possible and if so, any assistance to achieve this?

How i parse the JSON and add it to my arraylist:

```java
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
 new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

  Log.d("Volley response:", response.toString());
  //listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 progbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Parsing json
 for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

  try {

 JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

  Attendants model = new Attendants();

  model.setAttname(obj.getString("name"));

  model.setId(obj.getString("id"));
   //check for online value

if(obj.getString("online").equals("1")){

model.setOnline(obj.getString("online"));

 }else{
 //skip the block of JSON HOW??

 }
 modelList.add(model);

  } catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

 }
```

Comment: where is this json coming from? do you have a server, database etc?

Comment: The data comes from mysql database

Comment: i've added more code

Comment: call  modelList.add(model); inside if condition. Don't need the else part.

Comment: cant you just modify your SQL query not to get records that have online 0

Comment: @Tasos i can't because we using the same data elsewhere,that is why it has to be in java

Comment: ok that makes sense :)

Comment: I appreciate your input though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(obj.getString("online").equals("1")){

model.setOnline(obj.getString("online"));
modelList.add(model);

}
//skip the else block
```

Comment: This has worked..Amazing work friend!i appreciate it